# Adding retry logic to existing TCP connection with a tunnel

Tags: networking

I'm using a program that connects using TCP from one computer on my network to another. Often and for unknown reasons, the connection gets dropped. This connection is managed by a third-party program, so I can't edit the code and add retry logic there.

I was thinking, is there a program I can run that will:

1. Create a network tunnel between the two computers,
2. Have retry logic on that tunnel to make it resilient,
3. Expose the tunnel as a localhost port on the initiating computer?

That way I could tell my third-party program to connect to localhost:12345 and it'll be none the wiser to the retry logic added by my tunnel.

Does something like that exist?